# I get access violation writing location error when trying to allocate memory using CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I just started learning how to use CUDA api and I started with this introduction guide: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/even-easier-introduction-cuda/

I am following the tutorial but after I am trying to allocate memory with `cudaMallocManaged()` I want to initialize the array, but when trying to initialize the array, an exception is thrown, which says:

> Exception thrown at 0x003983D7 in VectorAdd.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

The program can identify my GPU, I know that because I made a function that writes all of my CUDA devices and my GPU is there.

this is my code, just as shown on the tutorial:

```
int main(void)
{
PrintCudaDevices();

int N = 1 << 20; //1M elements

float *x, *y;

cudaMallocManaged(&x, N * sizeof(float));
cudaMallocManaged(&y, N * sizeof(float));

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    x[i] = 1.0f;
    y[i] = 2.0f;
}
}
```

I googled that problem but I didn't find any working solution.

Comment: The problem is discussed [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/even-easier-introduction-cuda/#comment-3457108927) in the blog article you linked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was compiling it with x86, but when I compiled it on x64 it worked great. It didn't work with x86 because unified memory requires x64 bit OS. In addition, don't forget to call `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after any kernel if you want to use its results once it's done.